# Scipy - Opposite of incomplete gamma function

Tags: scipy, integral

I'm working on a super-simplified radiative transfer problem, and I end up with an integral of the form
\int_{x_0}^{x_1} e^{+t} t^a dt
in one of my equations.  Is there either:
1. A special name for such a function that I just haven't been able to find?  It's clearly related to the incomplete gamma function
\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)} \int_0^{x} e^{-t} t^{a-1} dt
which is implemented under `scipy.special.gammainc`.  I've already used that in an earlier part of my code.
2. A reasonably fast implementation of such a function, where the exponent $a$ is fixed but the integration bounds $x_{0,1}$ are variable?  Preferably one where $x_{0,1}$ can be numpy vectors of the same length, or where one is a scalar? (I can discuss how this fits into the problem if it would clarify things.)

Two straightforward work-arounds use `scipy.integrate.quad` or `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz`:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad  
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz  
from numpy import exp, empty_like, linspace, ones

a = 0.286 * 4.0
fIntegrand = lambda t: exp(t) * t**a

def FIntegrated1(x0,x1):
    # Use quad to do integrals one by one
    F = empty_like(x0)
    for i in xrange(x0.size):
        F[i] = quad(fIntegrand, x0[i], x1[i])[0]
    return F

def FIntegrated2(x):
    # Use cumtrapz
    # x is a numpy array from x0 to maximum x1 to be calculated
    F = cumtrapz(fIntegrand, x=x, initial=0.0)
    return F

# Test out with typical values
x = linspace(.5,8,50)
x1 = x[1:]
x0 = ones(x1.shape) * .5
F1 = FIntegrated1(x0,x1)
F2 = FIntegrated2(x)
```

Neither work-around is particularly slow or particularly fast, but a better approach would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for the (lower) incomplete gamma function in scipy: [(link)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainc.html#scipy.special.gammainc)

Comment: If I'm reading the question right, the OP is already familiar with this function.